# Saving a deep copy of an object, then modifying it and saving another copy?

Tags: python, copy

I have a 'GameBoard' class and am doing a search on it.  I want to save the current gameboard in a list, change the state of the gameboard, save THAT one in a list, and so on (so I would have incremental versions of the gameboard as a game progresses).

I'm currently doing this with copy.deepcopy, but it doesn't seem to be saving and moving on.  Here is a sample of my code:

```
    moves = [] # just for reference.  this has at least one value in it by the time the while loop hits.
    while winner is False and len(moves) > 0:
        g_string = gb.to_string()
        if g_string == win_string:
            winner = True
            break

        possibilities = gb.legal_moves(visited) # returns a list of possible moves to take

        if len(possibilities) > 0:
            moves.append(copy.deepcopy(gb))
            gb.perform(possibilities[0]) # this modifies gb, according to the gameplay move.
            # snipped, for brevity.
```

If after 100 iterations, I were to print `moves`, I would get 100 identical objects.  If I print the object each time before appending it, they are definitely different at the time of appending.

To clarify, I would like copies of these objects (for use in things like a graph, to perform DFS and BFS on)

Here is more of my GameBoard class

```
class GameBoard:
    number_of_rows = 3
    rows = []
    global random_puzzle

    def __init__(self, setup):
            #some code.  fills in the rows. adds some things to that list. etcetc..
            # more code
```

Comment: Why not save just the initial state and moves, then re-create the required board by applying moves to the initial state until you get to the move you want?

Comment: You're right, in some cases I would want to do that.  Thanks for the recommendation.  There are also cases where I want the physical objects, however.  (Well, not quite physical..)

Comment: Without posting your `GameBoard` class, there is no way for us to tell why `copy.deepcopy()` is failing.

Comment: I have updated the question with the skeleton of what the GameBoard class contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is valid for a simple dictionary object:

```
seq = 1
a_dict = {}
moves = []
while seq < 4:
 a_dict['key' + str(seq)] = 'value' + str(seq)
 moves.append(copy.deepcopy(a_dict))
 seq = seq + 1

print moves
```

Somehow for your object, deepcopy does not reach the contents of your gameboard.

Is your gameboard data somehow stored outside of the object in which case only a pointer to it is copied? Which state of the board is saved, the first or the last one? Can you post more details about the structure of your object?

---

EDIT: [Try adding your own getstate/setstate methods](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t354150-how-to-copy-a-python-object.html) in order to tell deepcopy what data needs to copied between instances. For example if your `rows` array contains the gameboard:

```
def __getstate__(self): 
    return self.rows

def __setstate__(self, rows): 
    self.rows = rows
```

Comment: The last one is saved, rather than the first one.  It's not making a whole lot of sense to me.

Comment: Well it makes more sense than the first one being stored. Apparently when the game is over and you are reading out your moves[] array to print the game board history, data from the current object is read. Can you post more code about the object and how you read out the gameboard?

Comment: Sure, I posted the skeleton of the GameBoard class

Comment: Thanks. It would also help if you would include the method that gives back the gameboard data, the one that keeps giving you back the same board.

Comment: Adding the above methods to the GameBoard class doesn't seem to change it.  I am stepping out for the night, but I will check the link you linked me to in the morning.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Hm. I created my own primitive GameBoard class to test it, and at first I had the same problem as you, but after adding those lines the problem was solved. Check it out for yourself, I posted the code online. You can remove and add the lines and see the difference. http://snipplr.com/view/41938/python-gameboard-class/

Comment: You just have to figure out which data is crucial for you to deepcopy and put that in one data structure. Anyhow.. goodnight! I hope the problem will be solved.